# how do I make kivy work ?I have an error installing it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, kivy

- "python -m pip install kivy" command didn't work.

**here is the error:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Python 3.7, or Kivy's latest pre-release.